# What tactics would be employed by armies with different light preferences?

Tags: medieval, fantasy-races, military

Say we have a men vs. orcs warfare scenario in a world with roughly medieval-type technology. The men can see well in daylight, but almost not at all at night. The orcs can see in the darkness of night, but are somewhat weakened in the light of day (but not hindered by lesser lights such as torches).

Presumably when armies march against each other in the surface world, they'll be jockeying to have engagements occur in their preferred light state (men in the day, orcs in the night). But I'm not sure exactly how that would play out.

What tactics would each side use to engage the opponent in the preferred part of the day/night? What defenses would each use to avoid being attacked when they're more vulnerable? Overall, what distribution of day-vs-night fights are likely to occur?

Comment: Are you intending to hamstring the orcs twice? Because you basically say they can't really see well in both day and night.

Comment: @DKNguyen: They can see distinctly better than men at night.

Comment: Other than the light dependence / weakness, are both sides economically and strategically equal?  That is, are they both surface-dwelling, feudal agricultural societies that hold territory and war against each other (but the orcs do their sowing, herding and harvesting at night)?  Or are the orcs basically cave-dwelling scavengers who raid the human surface holdings?  Also, what size units are involved? - concealing a squad of orcs during the day is very different to concealing a brigade.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055: Let's say they're roughly equal in economy, civilization, and strategy in the field. Orcs can have surface holdings with herding and harvesting (tended at night, in woods, shaded peaks, overcast/foggy days, etc.). Size of units I'm thinking is company to brigade size (hundreds to low thousands).

Comment: What is the nature of the orcish night vision? Is it infrared? Ultraviolet? Low-light vision? Pseudo-magical anti-light sight? I suspect there is going to be an advantage to humans, because prime campaigning season will also correlate to times of the year that there is more light. Winter isn't a good time to carry out war, usually. depends on seasonal variations on your world, I suppose.

Comment: @DWKraus: I'm hoping to not make a specific issue out of that. Let's say the men have no means with which to foil the specific see-in-dark mechanism, at least.

Comment: It depends also on how much your orcs may be shaped and their needs. Are they bigger and stronger than humans? or more like Tolkien's orcs (only the Uruk-hai were comparable in strength to men). Do they have trained animals to help their war effort? Not just for battle but also to move supplies and gear with the army. Are they faster and more resilient than men when in the dark? how about under sunshine, can they march at all? If your orcs are like Tolkien's they have a severe disadvantage and can only win through superior numbers (and a cover of volcanic ashes from Mount Doom)

Comment: @DuncanDrake: Let's say they're approximately the same as Tolkien in those respects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Attacks will occur when the attackers choose**

One general principle of military engagements is that the defenders choose the ground, the attackers choose the time.  No one is going to choose to attack when they are at a disadvantage, so the orcs will attack just before the middle of the night (preferably moonless) while the humans will attack shortly before noon (preferably on a bright, sunny day).

Open field battles can only occur by mutual consent, so they will not occur in human-orc battles - the humans are massively disadvantaged at night and the orcs are massively disadvantaged during the day.

The consequence is that protection at rest becomes vitally important.  The Roman legions would march each day for a sustained period and then dig in and fortify the camp they would stay in each night.  This pattern is vital for both sides - in order to survive an attack they *must* be protected by fortifications while at rest and they must have warning of a pending attack.  Sentries, observation posts and watch animals that can make up for their own sensory deficiencies will be critical.  Battles will occur when the visually advantaged group attacks the fortifications of the visually disadvantaged group, ideally in a location where they are unable to fortify effectively.

Strategically, the humans have a significant advantage.  Campaigns are normally conducted in summer because:

- in winter the cold is likely to kill more soldiers than the enemy and the ground is wet or frozen
- in spring most of the population is needed to sow the fields and many roads are still too wet at the start
- in autumn most of the population is needed to bring in the harvest and if the campaign takes longer than expected then all the disadvantages of winter are experienced.

These considerations still apply to both races, and days in summer are much longer than nights, giving humans a shorter window of vulnerability and a longer window of opportunity.  The orcs may be able to work harder during the summer nights than the humans can during the summer days given the lower night time temperatures, but the relative lengths of day and night are a significant disadvantage.

For those who are thinking that the orcs can be a bit hardier and attack in winter - they need to be *much* hardier, because the winter nights are colder than the winter days.  Essentially they are doubly disadvantaged in winter and are well-advised to hole up in their communities and work on their manufacturing, arts and crafts during the long winter nights.

Speculating on possible items that are still compatible with the general technology level - with sunglasses not available, the orcs want fine woven cloth that they can put over their eyes to protect from excessive light.  For those who have read the [Belgariad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Belgariad), think about the fine scarfs that Relg and his fellow cave-dwellers put over their eyes to protect from the outside light whenever they were above ground.  Conversely, the humans want the ability to create very bright light quickly to dazzle the orcs at night.  The simplest way is to have branches with dried leaves kept near a small fire and put them on when required, with an opaque screen on the "friendly" side/s to avoid dazzling humans.  Eyepatches are potentially valuable to both sides at night, so if one eye is dazzled then the other eye will still be effective.

Comment: One additional point is that the humans will always need to be sure they can start a light during the dark.  This requires that they had fuel to the already difficult task of supplying the army.  (It will probably complicate it but not make it insurmountable.)

Comment: Excellent answers (and mostly consensus) all around. I'm selecting this answer because it is (narrowly) the most upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

**Human heavy cavalry and horse archers, naffatun brigades/Orcish hobilars & heavy infantry:**

Wars are typically fought in the summer, when the roads are passable and labor is available after planting but before harvest. This also means that humans get a big leg up, because this is also when there's abundant sunlight and long days.

I'm making some assumptions, but I'm going to say orcish night vision is somewhat short ranged. Orcs will favor melee fighting and shorter ranged missile weapons they can use at night. I'm also guessing melee weapons favoring wild brawling fights would be best for orcs in the day, requiring less sight and more attacking things easy to see very close by. Orcs are likely to utilize heavy infantry and weapons, trying to draw opponents into grinding, brawling battles (ideally at dusk, so the enemy can see, but the tactical situation will keep improving for the orcs). The orcs are going to need to learn to sleep in the saddle, but not fight there. To counter the extra hours of daylight, the orcs must be on the march during the day when they can't see well. Horses can't see that well at night, so orcs will ride in the day, sleeping horseback as much as possible, but then dismount and fight on foot at night, when long-ranged human weapons will be ineffective.

Humans will do best using their excellent daylight vision to range their attacks. Horse archers can harass orcs all day long. Getting in a brawl with orcs is a good way to die, so they will want to maneuver to avoid bogged-down battle. This doesn't mean, however, humans won't mix it up. Tight infantry formations take advantage of tactics and pikes to hold the orcs in place and grind them while archers and even spear throwers kill them. Because horses favor light, heavy human cavalry will be able to smash orc formations and break off, while the orcs have trouble seeing what's going on. At night, humans in battle will be probably more challenged than orcs in the day, so I'm guessing humans will use a LOT of fire weapons to increase light on the field and coming from burning orcish formations. Smoke will obscure vision for orcs at night, but that doesn't hurt humans any more than it already is in the dark.

Answer (score 3):

In a medieval world it's possible to shed light in the dark but it's almost impossible to throw darkness in the day without magic.

I think the humans in your scenario have a big advantage: during the day they can seek and engage the orcs, while during the night they can use the light of large fires to hinder them and limit the attacking.

The orcs on the other hand can only rely on surprise attacks at night, but during the day they cannot have any way to block sunlight, other than hoping in storms and very cloudy days, maybe.

Comment: Creating darkness is easier than you think.  Set a dry field on fire and you'll bath any village downwind in a wall of choking darkness.  Lure your enemy into the bottom of a narrow valley and their sunlight advantage will last minutes, not hours.  And keep in mind this is in a pre-electric age.  If you meet your enemy in their homes and castle halls, you'll have all the darkness you can ever wish for.

Comment: Granted the limited range of torchlight for the men, do you think this tactic would present a vulnerability in that the orcs could stand at a distance and attack with missile weapons (bows, crossbows)?

Comment: @HenryTaylor Smoke is a lot less darkening than you think.  Valleys narrow enough for such tactics are extremely rare, especially given that it's daylight, not direct sunlight, that's the problem -- and they tend to be situated in less valuable land.  And the light is not significant if the enemy has already gotten into your castle halls, which is why that is made so difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You already have some good answers.
In addition / correction to @KerrAvon2055 good answer I'll add this:
Since the defender is dug in and the attacker chooses the moment humans will choose to attack at the break of dawn with the sun rising behind them.
It's a common tactic but would be even more effective against Orcs, effectively blinding them all. This would allow the humans to dismantle the defenses with little opposition.
Some of them may carry very polished metal convex shields to reflect sunlight if they can't attack with the sun behind them. In this case they will start from a position so that the sun will be in front of them, wait for it to be a bit over the horizon then attack while the shield bearers try to project the concentrated light on the enemy entrenchment. Any orc swept by the sunbeam would remain blind for several minutes. It's the same principle of Archimede's mirrors but the light would not need to be so concentrated, actually having a larger beam would be better.

edit: I see now OP's answer stating that these orcs are comparable to Tolkien's. Then they have significant disadvantage compared to humans and will unlikely win unless:

- they manage to set up an ambush in a dark place, like a deep forest
- manage to exploit a badly fortified position at night
  In both cases they will need to exploit a fundamental mistake made by their opponent.

Orcs are at disadvantage because:

- are smaller and weaker than humans (only Uruk-hais were comparable to men in strength
- they can't move in daylight without becoming quickly exhausted. So they would not be able to march during the day to fight at night. Which means that in Summer they would have a much reduced mobility compared to humans. Humans are most likely to impose the field of battle and the time

Orcs in the books had to their advantage an overwhelming number of troops and, in The Return Of The king, the cover of Mount Doom ashes. But OP has not specified either for his world.

Comment: Enter Archimedes and the Burning Mirror!  http://www.unmuseum.org/burning_mirror.htm

Comment: @chasly hahaha, no need to burn down the orcs. Just momentary blindness will suffice